# Conditional iterating for each

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hi i have a for each loop

```
For each bkmark in bookmarks
       If conditional statement is true
           Insert conditional value
            Next for
        End if
       Insert default value
Next``
```

How to do the next for?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a "next" here - just add an `Else` to your `If` block:

```
For each bkmark in bookmarks
   If conditional statement is true
       Insert conditional value
   Else
       Insert default value
   End if
Next
```